# Created exe file using auto-py-to-exe but its generated error

Tags: web, web-applications, pyinstaller, exe, auto-py-to-exe

I want to make .exe file of my web based application main file actually this web app is for video classification. however, when i converted into .exe file using auto-py-to-exe its created output folder and exe file but when i run this file its open front end but when i uploaded video and click on classification button its generated error

```
RuntimeError at /index/predictor
Unable to open fake_vid_detect1\shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/predictor
Django Version: 4.2.1
Exception Type: RuntimeError
Exception Value:
Unable to open fake_vid_detect1\shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat
Exception Location: inference_app\csv_generator.py, line 15, in ExtractingLandmarks
Raised during: inference_app.views.predictor
Python Executable: E:\Downloads\auto-py-to-exe-master\output\manage\manage.exe
Python Version: 3.10.11
Python Path:
['E:\\Downloads\\auto-py-to-exe-master\\output\\manage\\_internal\\base_library.zip',
'E:\\Downloads\\auto-py-to-exe-master\\output\\manage\\_internal\\lib-dynload',
'E:\\Downloads\\auto-py-to-exe-master\\output\\manage\\_internal']
Server time: Tue, 17 Oct 2023 09:33:02 +0000"
```

When creating the .exe file, I added all the required files and folders separately. I've tried many times, but the same error keeps occurring. I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Please don't post same text twice, and please format your questions for readability